# url rewrite and 404 error page not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using url rewrite like this

```
RewriteRule ^help$ help.php
```

so if user come with domain.com/help it work
but if user call page like domain.com/help/ it send err 404 page not found
how can fix this that in 2 case it do same job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^help/?$ help`
```

Adding `/?` makes the trailing-slash to be optional. The pattern then starts to match `help` as well as `help/`

You can test this rule [here](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the trailing slash in your regular expression optional:

```
RewriteRule ^help/?$ help.php
```